# Integral with several parameters

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

> Let $r>0$. Find $(p,q) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that the integral:
>   $$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{(x^{r}-1)^{p}}{x^{q}}} ~dx$$
>   converges and for those values calculate it.

I've already calculated the values for which it is convergent. The integral above converges iff $rp-q <-1$ or equivalently when $p<\frac{q-1}{r}$.

I get stuck when trying to calculate it. I've derived the integrand with respect to every parameter and then tried to substitute the order of integration but in all cases I get a non-elementary integral. Any ideas how to calculate this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe limit test with $1/x^q$? That may take care of some cases, but not all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carry out the substitution $y=x^{1-q}$ and then use Newton's generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: This is an attractive approach. If you could add more details, it would help me to understand whether it leads to calculation of the integral or just to a test for convergence.

Comment: It leads to a calculation of the integral. From Wikipedia, binomial theorem, $(a+b)^p=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {p\choose k} a^k b^{p-k}$.  In your case $a$ is a power of $x$ and hence so is $a^k$.

Comment: It would improve your Answer if you show the details of this.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\large\int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{x^{r} - 1}^{p} \over x^{q}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{1}^{0}{\pars{x^{-r} - 1}^{p} \over x^{-q}}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x^{r}}^{p} \over x^{pr - q + 2}}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{p} \over \pars{x^{1/r}}^{pr - q + 2}}
\,{1 \over r}\,x^{1/r - 1}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over r}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - x}^{p}x^{-p + \pars{q - 1}/r -1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over r}\,{\rm B}\pars{p + 1,-p + {q - 1 \over r}}}
\\[5mm]&\quad \Re\pars{{q - 1 \over r}} > \Re p > -1
\end{align}
where ${\rm B}\pars{x,y}$ is the *Beta function*.